# Activate Javascript with a click

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm currently trying to modify a primeFaces jQuery call which is triggered by the following javascript

Name /  Default / Type
filterEvent  / keyup  /  String

Currently the call is activated on keyup or keydown but I want it to activate when I click a button.  Let's say the button id is activateFilter.  Would the code be this?

```
filterEvent="activateFilter.click()"
```

I think I'm close but missing something.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment below, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code for calling a javascript function from a `<button />` or `<a />` tag could be done a few ways:

```
<button onclick="activateFilter();">Click Me</button> //or
<a href="javascript: activateFilter();return false;" >Click Me</a> //or
<a href="#" onclick="activateFilter();" >Click Me</a>
```

You could also do it like so if you're using jquery

```
//given this markup
<button id="myButton" />

//you could use jQuery like so
jQuery(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    activateFilter();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

**Update:**

If you're trying to use a click to trigger a function that listens to `keyUp`/`keyDown` etc, then why not "on click" emit/trigger the desired event. Something like so:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger("keyUp", eventObject);
  return false;
});
```

Obviously you would need to check which event primefaces' activateFilter() function is listening on and what the eventObject being passes looks like when you do trigger that event naturally (ie: by pressing the required button/key) then mimic that event on click.

Also see jQuery docs for `.keyup();` http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ as a possible way of mimicing a keypress.

Comment: I understand that much but the problem comes from the way that the filterEvent is called.  It needs to be activated by a DOM Event such as keyUP or keyDown.  Click is a DOM event but I need to figure out how to pass the button click to filterEvent.

Comment: This is semi close.. I think I maybe wording my example wrongly.

The method fires off if any of the following are done:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

what I'm looking for is if it can pick a particular button to activate this method.